# In date time picker i want to hide the default settled date

Tags: datepicker

I'm using a date-time picker, when I refresh the page it shows the current date.I want that it show the date when I selected the date otherwise it show nothing. In other words, I want to hide the default date

```
                  <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <label>Select Date</label>
                <input type="text" id="picker" name="BillSearch[issue_date]" class="form-control">


             <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>

            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css"/>

            <script type="text/javascript">
    
                $('#picker').daterangepicker({

                    startDate:moment().subtract(29,'days'),
                    endDate:moment(),
                    Current: false, 
                     'opens':'left',
        'ranges': {
'Today': [moment(), moment()],
              'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
              'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
              'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
              'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
              'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],

        },


            


                                    });



            </script>
     
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using DateRangePicker.
According to their [doc](https://www.daterangepicker.com/) you could do something like this to initially empty.
Pay attention to the value used in your input, that would determine the initial value.
The events are optional but if you see on the cancel.daterangepicker you have another way of setting the value to empty.

```
<input type="text" name="datefilter" value="" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false,
      locale: {
          cancelLabel: 'Clear'
      }
  });

  $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
  });

  $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
      $(this).val('');
  });

});
</script>
```